# Variance of a special random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random, random-walk

I am trying to find the variance of the following special random walk:

Suppose that $U=(U_1,U_2,...)$ is a sequence of independent random variables, each taking values $u$ (for *up*) and $d$ (for *down*) with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Let $X=(X_0,X_1,X_2,...)$ be the partial sum process associated with $U$ so that $$X_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n U_i, \hspace{1cm} n\in\mathbb{N}$$

The mean of this process is $$\mathbb{E}(X_n)=n\cdot p\cdot(u+d)$$

**My question**
What is the variance $var(X_n)$?

Comment: OK. What about the variance of $X_1$?

Comment: Re the Edit: The additivity of the variances of sums is guaranteed as soon as independence holds, for every distribution, whether skewed or not.

Comment: Impossible to say since you do not show said calculations but only the (wrong) result you arrive at.

Comment: What do you call var(a,b) and var(a,b,c,d) for real numbers (a,b,c,d)? Never saw the notation.

Comment: @Did: You asked for the bigger context of this problem and I posted another question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309230/variance-of-the-sums-of-all-combinations-of-a-set-of-numbers - This time I really tried hard to give all the necessary information, let's see if this is sufficient for your critical eye ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $U_n$ are i.i.d. then
$$\mathrm{Var}(X_n) = \mathrm{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n U_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Var}(U_i) = n\mathrm{Var}(U_1).$$

Comment: Thanks for catching my typo @Did :)